# How to split a column using only Sql?

Tags: sql, plsql

Lets say my table is like,

```
   data
   ----
   smith700
```

then my output should be

```
   name  sal
  -----  --- 
  smith  700
```

I only can use SQL statement no PL/SQL statement is allowed...How to do it?

Comment: What is the criteria for splitting? First 5 characters in `name`, rest in `sal`?

Comment: have you tried anything at all ?

Comment: Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` - this way you can split items with letters only and items with start with digits

Comment: @T.S. if you'd posted this as an answer I would have upvoted. Technically the other answers are correct, but it seems unlikely to me that all his names are exactly 5 characters long in which case you'd be looking at a solution such as your `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

Comment: Nevertheless the answers are correct regarding your question. You never mentioned different name length or that last part is only numbers and so on.

Comment: @CompuChip I would posted it as answer if I would want to spend time figuring out `regex` expression. As is, it is a comment material. I gave the light, let the developer to follow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SubStr](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)

```
SELECT SUBSTR('smith700',1,5),SUBSTR('smith700',6,3)
```

**UPDATE**

For varying lengths of numbers and characters you could try

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('smith700', '[A-Za-z]','') FROM DUAL;
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('smith700', '[0-9]') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: ya that could be done but if i have multiple rows with different names and salary(the length of the name is different) then what to do?

Comment: but regexp_replace may cause some other problem do we have some other process of doing it....

Answer (score -1):

```
 select substr(data,1,5) name, substr(data,6,3) sal from your_tab;
```